# Is it possible to develop multiple WP8 app under a single solution?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to develop multiple WP8 app under a single solution? (similar to multiple projects per workspace in IOS)

Comment: Yes. Have you tried adding a new project to the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible: [MSDN : Multi-Project Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/23x5fk78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That apply to various type of projects, including WP8 project (you can even mix WP8, with other type projects). It is makes sense that you want to run only one WP8 project at a time, so don't forget to [set start up project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a1awth7y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before running the solution.